# Store add_graph appears to do nothing with rdflib and Fuseki

Tags: fuseki, rdflib

I have a Fuseki endpoint and want to use the python rdflib library to add graphs to it.

I connect to the Fuseki server as follows:

```
import rdflib

from rdflib import Graph, Literal, URIRef
from rdflib.plugins.stores import sparqlstore

query_endpoint = 'http://localhost:3030/dsone/query'
update_endpoint = 'http://localhost:3030/dsone/update'
store = sparqlstore.SPARQLUpdateStore()
store.open((query_endpoint, update_endpoint))
```

Then I set-up an rdflib ConjunctiveGraph as follows:

```
g = rdflib.ConjunctiveGraph(identifier=URIRef("http://localhost/dsone/g3"))

g.parse(data="""
@base <http://example.com/base> .
@prefix : <#> .
<> a :document1 .
""", format='turtle', publicID = "http://example.com/g3")
```

`g` now contains one triple:

```
for r in g:
    print(r)
```

Which results in:

> (rdflib.term.URIRef('http://example.com/base'), rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type'), rdflib.term.URIRef('http://example.com/base#document1'))

Now I add the graph to the store with:

```
store.add_graph(g)
```

The server shows a `200` return code.  When I do the insert directly over REST, it returns 204 - which could be a clue.

Now there is *nothing* in the store.

```
for r in store.query("""
select ?g (count(*) as ?count) {graph ?g {?s ?p ?o .}} group by ?g
"""):
    print(r)
```

Which has no output.

As far as I can tell `store.add_graph(g)` is doing nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
store.add_graph(g)
```

Just created the graph itself, it won't take your graph content and put it in there. So `add_graph()` is really only just using the graph's identifier, not it's data.

Try calling `add_graph()` *then* adding data to the graph.